# Join to table on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

Unsure if i've used the correct question name here so feel free to suggest edits

Assume the following table structure:

```
Jobs Table:
|jobID|jobName|
---------------
|1 |     Test_1|
|2 |     Test_2|
|3 |     Test_3|

jobType Table:
|jobTypeID|  jobId| jobTypeValueId |
--------------------
|1 |      1|     57|
|2 |      1|     64|
|3 |      1|     23|
|4 |      2|     64|
|5 |      2|     23|
|6 |      3|     64|
|7 |      3|     99|
```

jobType Foreign Keys - jobId, jobTypeValueId, by which I mean to imply that (jobid, jobTypeValueId) is UNIQUE.

**Assume im trying to return jobId 2; how do I go about querying all jobs that have associated jobTypeValueId records of 23 and 64 and ONLY those records?**

Things i've tried:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM job j
  LEFT 
  JOIN jobType jt 
    on j.jobId = jt.jobId
 WHERE jt.jobTypeValueId = 23
   AND jt.jobTypeValueId = 64

SELECT * 
  FROM job j
  LEFT 
  JOIN jobType jt 
    on j.jobId = jt.jobId 
   AND jt.jobId = 23
  LEFT 
  JOIN jobType jt2 
    on j.jobId = jt2.jobId 
   AND jt.jobId = 64
 WHERE jt.jobTypeValueId = 23
   AND jt2.jobTypeValueId = 64

SELECT * 
  FROM job j
  LEFT 
  JOIN jobType jt 
    on j.jobId = jt.jobId
 WHERE jt.jobTypeValueId IN (23, 64)
 GROUP 
    BY j.jobId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT jt.jobTypeValueId) = 2
```

The last example is the closest i've come - but it will also return jobId 3, since one of the jobs returned jobType rows matches one of the values in `WHERE jt.jobTypeValueId IN (23, 64)`

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: It is, its the Foreign Key of another table

Comment: I suggest you edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I have now done this. Hopefully its easy enough to understand